# Issue with API url: cannot seem to pass parameters correctly

Tags: javascript, api, url, parameter-passing, flickr

I'm new at APIs and am trying for the first time to create a gallery using Flickr API, but I'm really struggling getting it to work properly.

I have created the url correctly, and if I insert the search parameters directly in the url, when I console log I can see the correct list of images. The issue occurs when I'm trying to pass parameters from variables into the url. And the error manifests in two different ways, depending whether I put the url variable before or after the parameters variables.

Case 1:

```
var url = `https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&text=${searchWord}&per_page=${perPage}&page=${page}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`;
var searchWord = document.getElementById('input').value;
var perPage = 50;
var page = 1;
```

In this case it will console log data, but using parameters of its choice.

Case 2:

```
var searchWord = document.getElementById('input').value;
var perPage = 50;
var page = 1;
var url = `https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&text=${searchWord}&per_page=${perPage}&page=${page}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`;
```

In this case it will return the following error message: *{stat: "fail", code: 3, message: "Parameterless searches have been disabled. Please use flickr.photos.getRecent instead."}*

I seem to not be passing parameters to the url correctly, cause I'm also having an issue when trying to create the gallery itself, where when I'm trying to pass the necessary ids from the images in the API array to the image url I'm creating, these parameters end up being undefined.

This is the code I've written:

```
function createGallery(photos) {

    for (let photo of Object.keys(photos)) {
        const imgElem = document.createElement('li');
        imgElem.innerHTML = `<img src='https://farm{${photo.farm}}.staticflickr.com/{${photo.server}}/{${photo.id}}_{${photo.secret}}_[mstzb].jpg'></img>`;
        imgElem.setAttribute('img-id', photo.id);
        gallery.append(imgElem);
    }
}
```

Just for an overview, here is the last bit of my JS:

```
//Fetch API
async function start() {
    const response = await fetch (url)
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
    createGallery(data)
}


//Call functions
search()
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <main>
        <input type="text" id="input">
        <button id="search">Go</button>

        <ul id="gallery"></ul>
        
    </main>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong?? Thanks so much in advance :)

EDIT: I tried appending the variables using pluses instead of using template literals, like so:

```
var url = 'https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&text='+searchWord+'&per_page='+perPage+'&page='+page+'&format=json&nojsoncallback=1';
```

But both ways give exactly the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically appending the parameters incorrectly.

You have the following:

```
var perPage = 50;
var page = 1;
var url = `https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&text=${searchWord}&per_page=${perPage}&page=${page}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`;
```

When you define that url it should be similar to this ..

```
var url = `https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&text=' + searchWord + '&per_page=' + perPage + '&page=' + page + '&format=json&nojsoncallback=1'
```

Please note the difference there, we are actually just building up the url var by appending the JS variables to the String. There is no ${} access to the declared page and perPage JS vars...

Comment: I probably should have mentioned, I've tried using 'https://etc..' + searchWord+ 'etc..', but the result is exactly the same. Whether I use template literals or appending the variables with pluses, it still doesn't work

Comment: Could you do a console.log or a JavaScript alert on the url just so that we can see the URL that you have built up in the JS Code please..

Comment: Very useful this service i.e. https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search

Comment: I just got some in real life help and figured out what the problem was! I was supposed to add the ".value"  next to searchWord in the url rather than in the variable. All working now. Thanks for your answers :)